# WhirlyGlobe : Getting compilation error while trying to use framework

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am trying to use the open source app WhirlyGlobe from link: http://code.google.com/p/whirlyglobe/

I am using following steps to use it in my app:

1. adding framework to application framework.
2. Copying the supporting files to my project (Utilities folder from whirlyglobe code) and setting Header Search Path as utilities/boost_1_45_0 & utilities/eigen-eigen-3.0.1
3. renaming my file to .mm and then trying to draw the map.

**Problem here is i am getting compilation error :"'set' file not found".**

This file is present under 'Utilities' folder. I am not getting what wrong i am doing. I even tried changing header paths but didn't helped.

If anybody have used this library , please help me out telling correct steps.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension of your file from .m to .mm

Comment: Make sure all the files you're including WhirlyGlobe in have the .mm extension.  

You should probably email directly.  I don't scan stackoverflow very often and my automatic notifier doesn't seem to work reliably.